# Why should I convert List into Array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Look into following line of code:

```
public string[] GetStringList(params object[] values)
{
    List<string> _stringList = new List<string>();

    foreach (object value in values)
    {
        _stringList.Add(Convert.ToString(value));

        //Do something
    }

    //Why this invalid?
    return _stringList;

    //Why do required to convert list collection in array
    return _stringList.ToArray();
}
```

Since List and Array both are colletions then why should I need to convert List into Array?

Comment: It's your code. If it were mine, I'd probably leave it as a List. What prompted this question?

Comment: It could be that the place where you are calling this method , application expects an array.

Comment: Both ships and trucks haul containers.  Why should I ever need to move a container from one to the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since List and Array both are collections then why should I need to convert List into Array?

Yes, they are both collections, but your method signature specifies exactly what **type of** collection it returns, and that's why you have to return exactly that one collection type.

You can change your method declaration to return *collection of strings* using one of collection interfaces:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetStringList(params object[] values)
```

or

```
public ICollection<string> GetStringList(params object[] values)
```

It will allow you to return both `List<string>` and `string[]`, because they both implement the interface. You could also return `HashSet<string>` or even `Queue<string>` (for `IEnumerable<string>` version only. Or write your own class, implement the interface you're interested in and return it within your method.

But as soon as you declare the method using `string[]`, you have to return something that is an array of `string`s, and `List<string>` does not fulfill that requirement.

***OFT advice***

You can make your code a little faster passing `values.Length` as `List<string>` constructor parameter:

```
List<string> _stringList = new List<string>(values.Length);
```

it will initialize list internal storage with necessary amount of memory and let you add all your items without reallocating any memory.

Answer (score 4):

It is invalid to return the list directly because the specified return type is an array

```
          ↓
public string[] GetStringList(params object[] values)
```

If you want to return a list instead, it should be

```
public List<string> GetStringList(params object[] values)
```

If you want both to be valid, you could make the method return an `IEnumerable` (or another interface both types implement, like `ICollection`) like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetStringList(params object[] values)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Array` and `List` are two different things, `Dictionary` is also a collection then why dictionary and array are the same?. There are so many types of collections and they all are different from each other. If you do not want to convert then you shall return list instead of Array.

```
public List<string> GetStringList(params object[] values)
{
    List<string> _stringList = new List<string>(); 
    foreach (object value in values)        
    {
        _stringList.Add(Convert.ToString(value));
        //Do something
    }
    return _stringList;         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function return `string[]` instead of `List<string>` that's as you want.

```
public List<string> GetStringList(params object[] values)
    {
        List<string> _stringList = new List<string>();

        foreach (object value in values)
        {
            _stringList.Add(Convert.ToString(value));

            //Do something
        }
        //Why do required to convert list collection in array
        return _stringList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned they are both Collections, that means, they both implemented `ICollection`, but like inheritance, the most specific objects are **different** things but have **some**   characteristics that are the **same**. For example, suppose that we have tow classes:

```
class Plant : ILivingOrganism {...}
class Human: ILivingOrganism {...}
```

they have both implemented `ILivingOrganism` interface, that they have some characteristics which are the same, like `void Grow()` behavior which means they both can grow because they are living organism, **but** the thing is they are two different things even though they share some characteristics which are the same. Now when I write a method that returns `Plant` obviously you cannot expect it to return a `Human`, **but** with a method that returns `ILivingOrganism`, like `ILivingOrganism Clone()`, you can expect **any** living organism (more general type), like `Human` or `Plant`, technically everything that implements `ILivingOrganism`.